# I can't login after changing password with `password_hash` PHP

Tags: php, php-password-hash

After changing my password with `password_hash` I can no longer login, I can login with the password created during registration but after changing it I can no longer login. What am I missing?

```
// change password
public function update_user_passwd($user_id,$user_passwd) {
    $passwd = password_hash($user_passwd, PASSWORD_DEFAULT);
    $update_passwd = $this->_db->prepare('UPDATE `users` SET `user_pass`= ? WHERE `user_id` = ?');
    $update_passwd->bindValue(1,$passwd,  PDO::PARAM_STR);
    $update_passwd->bindValue(2,$user_id,  PDO::PARAM_INT);
    try {
        $update_passwd->execute();
        return 1;
    } catch (PDOException $exc) {
        return 0;
    }
    }
 //login
public function login($user_email, $user_passwd) {
    //login the user to the system. 
    try {
        $stmt = $this->_db->prepare("SELECT * FROM `users` WHERE `user_email` = :umail");
        $stmt->execute(array(':umail' => $user_email));
        $userRow = $stmt->fetch(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC);
        $hash = $userRow['user_pass'];
        $user_status = $userRow['user_status'];
        $user_id = $userRow['user_id'];
        if ($stmt->rowCount() > 0) {
            return $this->login_user($user_passwd, $hash, $user_status, $user_id);
        }
    } catch (PDOException $e) {
        echo $e->getMessage();
    }
}
private function login_user($user_passwd, $hash, $user_status, $user_id, $remember_me) {
    if (password_verify($user_passwd, $hash) && $user_status === 'active') {
        $_SESSION['web_user'] = $user_id;
        return TRUE;
    } else {
        return FALSE;
    }
}
```

my password column is 255 characters long.

Comment: what is password_verify() function??

Comment: it's in the last function `password_verify($user_passwd,$hash)`